# (ssg-wsg) Keep getting error with error code 403

Tags: ssg

i am in UAT Phase and try to call the UAT API but keep getting error with error code 403, what shd i do to be able to call the API, below pict is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBR2w.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be enough information to tell what is the problem. Since you are given UAT access, the proper channel would be to contact their service desk on your issue: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/faq?anchor=WhoCanIContactIfIHaveQuestionsAboutTheseAPIs

Comment: So, do i need something like Client ID and Client Secret during UAT Test?
because in my app i don't see any button to generate those things.